# Text file has different sized margins

Tags: windows, text, dos

Why is that saving a file via dosbox has two different margins. If I use a regular DOS text editor like EDIT the margins are like the one on the right. But something different happens if I use wordperfect. Saving it as "DOS TEXT" makes it appear as the one on the right as normal, but saving it as "generic" makes it look like the left as if I used a regular windows text editor. Why? Why does it do that?

[Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fl2k7.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is because your NPP processing, or not processing EOL (End Of Line).
You can see them going View>Show Symbols>Show End of Line menu. Or click as below:

[image: here]
You can change it's behavior by going Edit>EOL conversion> and choose from there.

Comment: The DOS TEXT one varies based on the editor in question, but the common theme is that DOS TEXT has [CR][LF] at the end of each line unlike generic which doesn't.